# json data grouping in multiple category

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, knockout.js, arraylist

```
[{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":1,"KeyId":1,"CategoryID":1,"KeyName":"displayDocumentTypeField","CategoryName":"CategoryType1","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":2,"KeyId":2,"CategoryID":1,"KeyName":"displayAttachmentTypeField","CategoryName":"CategoryType1","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":3,"KeyId":3,"CategoryID":3,"KeyName":"displayFormTypeField","CategoryName":"CategoryType3","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":4,"KeyId":4,"CategoryID":1,"KeyName":"maximumAttachmentFileSize","CategoryName":"CategoryType1","PartnerSupportedValue":"6291456","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":5,"KeyId":5,"CategoryID":2,"KeyName":"UseExternalRealtimeCalls","CategoryName":"CategoryType2","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":6,"KeyId":6,"CategoryID":1,"KeyName":"withdrawalExpiredDays","CategoryName":"CategoryType1","PartnerSupportedValue":"10","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":7,"KeyId":7,"CategoryID":2,"KeyName":"fundTransferExpiredDays","CategoryName":"CategoryType2","PartnerSupportedValue":"5","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":8,"KeyId":8,"CategoryID":2,"KeyName":"serviceFeatureExpiredDays","CategoryName":"CategoryType2","PartnerSupportedValue":"10","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":9,"KeyId":9,"CategoryID":2,"KeyName":"SupportsAttachmentForApplication","CategoryName":"CategoryType2","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":10,"KeyId":10,"CategoryID":3,"KeyName":"SupportsAttachmentForSubpay","CategoryName":"CategoryType3","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":11,"KeyId":11,"CategoryID":3,"KeyName":"rtcEmailNotificationInfo","CategoryName":"CategoryType3","PartnerSupportedValue":"{\"to\" : \"agniswar.das@Ebix.com, amarjeets@ebix.com\",  \"from\" : \"AnnuityNet4Notifications@Ebix.com\",  \"subject\" : \"Realtime call failure for [PARTNERNAME], [TRANSACTIONID]\", \"body\" : \"Realtime call type [REALTIMECALLTYPE] ([REALTIMECALLGUID]) failed at [DATETIME]. Please contact system administrator.\" , \"enable\" : \"false\" }","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":12,"KeyId":12,"CategoryID":3,"KeyName":"rtcRetryIncludes","CategoryName":"CategoryType3","PartnerSupportedValue":"{\"CurrentTransactionData\":\"5\"}","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":19,"KeyId":19,"CategoryID":1,"KeyName":"SpecialCharAllow","CategoryName":"CategoryType1","PartnerSupportedValue":"^(?!.*(<|>)).*[a-zA-Z0-9 @!#$%^&()_+-={}:;'\\\",.?|\\/~`\\n]+$","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":true,"IsActive":null}]
```

I have json data i want to make it in a group on the basis of categoryName, after it in every group, i want to make array for jquery nested template.

```
categoryList{
        categoryName = '',
        systemParameter[],
        customParameter[]
}
```

I have done some change but unable get expected result, please guide me anyone if possible.

```
var partnerSettingList = function () {
    this.categoryName = '';
    this.customSettingList = [];
    this.systemSettingList = []; };

var partnerSettingCategory = function (result) {


    var partnerSettingResults = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        var item = result[i];
        if (!partnerSettingResults[item.CategoryName]) {
            partnerSettingResults[item.CategoryName] = [];
        }
        partnerSettingResults[item.CategoryName].push({
            partnerSettingItem: item
        });
    }

    var partnerSettingCategoryList = [];

    for (var x in partnerSettingResults) {
        if (partnerSettingResults.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            var obj = {};
            obj[x] = partnerSettingResults[x];
            partnerSettingCategoryList.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return partnerSettingData(partnerSettingCategoryList)   }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want a distinct categories list and each one should have collection of its record?

Comment: Yes sir, I want a distinct category List and one should have collection of its records.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, then accept it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, and let me know if you find any issue.

```js
var data = [{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":1,"KeyId":1,"CategoryID":1,"KeyName":"displayDocumentTypeField","CategoryName":"CategoryType1","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":2,"KeyId":2,"CategoryID":1,"KeyName":"displayAttachmentTypeField","CategoryName":"CategoryType1","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":3,"KeyId":3,"CategoryID":3,"KeyName":"displayFormTypeField","CategoryName":"CategoryType3","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":4,"KeyId":4,"CategoryID":1,"KeyName":"maximumAttachmentFileSize","CategoryName":"CategoryType1","PartnerSupportedValue":"6291456","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":5,"KeyId":5,"CategoryID":2,"KeyName":"UseExternalRealtimeCalls","CategoryName":"CategoryType2","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":6,"KeyId":6,"CategoryID":1,"KeyName":"withdrawalExpiredDays","CategoryName":"CategoryType1","PartnerSupportedValue":"10","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":7,"KeyId":7,"CategoryID":2,"KeyName":"fundTransferExpiredDays","CategoryName":"CategoryType2","PartnerSupportedValue":"5","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":8,"KeyId":8,"CategoryID":2,"KeyName":"serviceFeatureExpiredDays","CategoryName":"CategoryType2","PartnerSupportedValue":"10","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":9,"KeyId":9,"CategoryID":2,"KeyName":"SupportsAttachmentForApplication","CategoryName":"CategoryType2","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":10,"KeyId":10,"CategoryID":3,"KeyName":"SupportsAttachmentForSubpay","CategoryName":"CategoryType3","PartnerSupportedValue":"False","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":11,"KeyId":11,"CategoryID":3,"KeyName":"rtcEmailNotificationInfo","CategoryName":"CategoryType3","PartnerSupportedValue":"{\"to\" : \"agniswar.das@Ebix.com, amarjeets@ebix.com\",  \"from\" : \"AnnuityNet4Notifications@Ebix.com\",  \"subject\" : \"Realtime call failure for [PARTNERNAME], [TRANSACTIONID]\", \"body\" : \"Realtime call type [REALTIMECALLTYPE] ([REALTIMECALLGUID]) failed at [DATETIME]. Please contact system administrator.\" , \"enable\" : \"false\" }","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":12,"KeyId":12,"CategoryID":3,"KeyName":"rtcRetryIncludes","CategoryName":"CategoryType3","PartnerSupportedValue":"{\"CurrentTransactionData\":\"5\"}","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":false,"IsActive":null},{"PartnerId":150,"SystemKeyId":19,"KeyId":19,"CategoryID":1,"KeyName":"SpecialCharAllow","CategoryName":"CategoryType1","PartnerSupportedValue":"^(?!.*(<|>)).*[a-zA-Z0-9 @!#$%^&()_+-={}:;'\\\",.?|\\/~`\\n]+$","SystemSuportedValue":"False[False],True[True],Test[Test]","CustomForPartner":true,"IsActive":null}];

var categories = [];
//Creating distinct list of Categories.
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value.CategoryName, categories)==-1) {
        categories.push(value.CategoryName);
    }
});

console.log(categories);

var finalCollection = [];
//Creating nested collection of categories and related objects.
categories.forEach(function(c){
    var result = $.grep(data, function(e){    return e.CategoryName == c; });
    finalCollection.push({
        CategoryName : c,
        Data : result
    });
});
console.log(finalCollection);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Moksh Shah, its working for me , Now i can customize the final Collection According to my requirements.

Comment: Yep, finalCollection object will have nested data, you may customize as per your requirement, you may appreciate it by accepting it as answered